# MooTools class binding with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, mootools, coffeescript

How can I write the following in CoffeeScript?

```
showMessage: function() {
    $('myelement').addEvent('click', function() {
        alert(this.options.message);
    }.bind(this));
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following should work:

```
SomeClass = new Class
  showMessage: ->
     $('myelement').addEvent 'click', =>
       alert @options.message
```

CoffeScript is a bit weird, and it always outputs `return` everywhere, this can sometimes cause problems, but most of the time it doesn't.

Comment: Totally right. Also note that the `=>` "bound function operator" works whether or not the browser defines `Function.prototype.bind`, which the questioner's code relies on. (It's not supported in IE8 and even the Safari 5, though you can define it with a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility).)

Comment: I don't know why you chose to add a class into this, you could just write `showMessage = ->`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works. Here is a full example:

```
SomeClass = new Class
    Implements: Options
    options: {}
    initialize: (options)->
        @setOptions options
        return
showMessage: ->
    $('myelement').addEvent 'click', =>
        alert @options.message
```